# In Ruby, how to create UTC datetime without timezone?

Tags: ruby, datetime, utc

I have the below code:

```rb
require 'time'
utc = DateTime.parse("2019-01-01 00:00:00", "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
puts utc
```

which outputs `2019-01-01T00:00:00+00:00`. How can I get this to be in the format `2019-01-01 00:00:00`?

Comment: This really just sounds like a question about how to format a DateTime into a string, hiding certain information you don't care about.  So what exactly do you mean when you say the result should not be a string?  Can you specify clearly what type of answer you would accept?

Comment: "Note that the result should not be a string" - what does this mean exactly?

Comment: I have made an edit. I was not aware that you could not format datetime withotu converting it to a string. The result can be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line to:

```rb
puts utc.strftime('%F %T')
```

For similar questions in the future, refer to the documentation of DateTime's strftime method:

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: Your link to https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime returns a 404.